# Tensorflow compatibility with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, version, compatibility

I am using Python 3.6 and Tensorflow 2.0, and have some Keras codes:

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

When I run this code, I got the following error:

> Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via pip
> install tensorflow

I checked on https://keras.io/, it says Keras was built on Tensorflow 2.0.
So I am confused. What exact version of Tensorflow does latest Keras support? and how to fix the above error? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that the latest `keras` version (2.4.x) is just a wrapper on top of `tf.keras`, which I do not think is that you want, and this is why it requires specifically TensorFlow 2.2 or newer.

What you can do is install Keras 2.3.1, which supports TensorFlow 2.x and 1.x, and is the latest real releases of Keras. You can also install Keras 2.2.4 which only supports TensorFlow 1.x. You can install specific versions like this:

```
pip install --user keras==2.3.1
```

Answer (score 16):

Just check Tensorflow and Keras compatibility:

[image]

and install compatible Tensorflow version. Check [this link](https://mckayward.github.io/floyd-docs/guides/environments/) for more info.

Comment: link not working.

Comment: link is incorrect!

Comment: I guess they changed the content of the link 

Answer (score 9):

That configuration can be tricky.  How about you use `keras` inside `tensorflow`?  I think they are more likely to be compatible each other.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

Answer (score 2):

## keras vs tf.keras

There are two implementations of the Keras API: the standalone Keras (installed with `pip install keras`), and tf.keras which is bundled with TensorFlow (`pip install tensorflow`).

A while back, standalone Keras used to support multiple backends, namely TensorFlow, Microsoft Cognitive Toolkit, Theano, and PlaidML. However, after Theano was abandoned, Keras dropped support for all of these except TensorFlow. So everyone started using tf.keras instead of the standalone Keras.

## Using tf.keras

To use tf.keras, you can simply install TensorFlow (`pip install tensorflow`) and use `from tensorflow import keras`. There's no need to install the standalone `keras` package, and there's no risk of compatibility issues:

```py
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Alternatively, you can just prefix everything with `tf.keras`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

## Keras core

However, in 2023, standalone Keras made a big come back: it once again supports multiple backends, namely TensorFlow, PyTorch, and JAX. The preview version is called Keras Core. To use it, simply `pip install keras-core`, then use `import keras_core as keras`:

```py
import keras_core as keras

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The first time you import `keras_core`, it will look for the `KERAS_BACKEND` environment variable to determine which backend to use. It can be `"tensorflow"`, `"torch"`, or `"jax"`. It will save that in `~/.keras/keras.json` and use it whenever the environment variable is not defined.

## Keras 3

Note that the final version of Keras Core will be called Keras 3, and you will be able to install it using `pip install keras`.

Moreover, tf.keras will no longer be maintained separately, it will simply use Keras 3 (so installing `tensorflow` will automatically install `keras` as well). `tf.keras` will simply be an alias for `keras`. All the Keras code will live at https://github.com/keras-team/keras.

So in the near future, the code will be:

```py
import keras

model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score -1):

Refer to Official Contents tensorflow.org with detailed info COMPATIBLE versions with CUDA, Tensorflow Version, Python Version, CuDNN: 
For Windows: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#cpu 
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu

For Linux: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#linux 
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu

For MacOS: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#macos 
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu_2