# ImportError: cannot import name 'get_keras_submodule' from partially initialized module 'keras_applications' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I use python 3.8.6 and I have loaded Keras 2.2.2, TensorFlow-GPU 2.2.0.

When I run my code, I have this error:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XX.py", line 23, in <module>
    import keras
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import applications
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras/applications/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    import keras_applications
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_applications/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from keras_applications import vgg16
  File ".local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_applications/vgg16.py", line 15, in <module>
    from . import get_keras_submodule
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_keras_submodule' from partially initialized module 'keras_applications' (most likely due to a circular import) (/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/keras_applications/__init__.py)
```

How to solve this error other than downgrade the TensorFlow version?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow compatibility with Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62690377/tensorflow-compatibility-with-keras)

Comment: `pip install Keras-Preprocessing` should fix this error. Thanks!